# RadioButton inside Table using Blazor

Tags: html, blazor, matblazor

First of all, I am using `Blazor WebAssembly 3.2.0 Preview 4`.

I have a list of objects named ObjectList and each object has an bool property named `principal`. This list populates a table.

The logic is that only one element in the list can have the value of `principal` property set to true so this is why radio buttons are ideal.

In this example, I am using MatBlazor as a library for controls.

Is there a way to put radiobutton for this property inside a table as in the code below?

```
<table class="table table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Object</th>
            <th>Principal</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var object in ObjectList)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@object .name</td>
            <td>
                <MatRadioButton TValue="bool" Value="@object.principal"></MatRadioButton>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The MatRadioButton button goes inside a MatRadioGroup:

```
    <MatRadioGroup @bind-Value="@Val1" TValue="string">
        <MatRadioButton Value="@string.Empty" TValue="string">Default</MatRadioButton>
        <MatRadioButton Value="@("f")" Label="Female" TValue="string"></MatRadioButton>
        <MatRadioButton Value="@("m")" TValue="string">Male</MatRadioButton>
        <MatRadioButton Value="@("d")" Disabled="true" TValue="string">Disabled</MatRadioButton>
    </MatRadioGroup>
    @code
    {

        protected string Val1;
    }
```

[MatRadioButton Documenation](https://www.matblazor.com/RadioButton)

So in your case, it might be something like:

```
<MatRadioGroup @bind-Value="@object.principal" TValue="bool">   
   <MatRadioButton Value="true" TValue="bool">True</MatRadioButton>
   <MatRadioButton Value="false" TValue="bool">False</MatRadioButton>
</MatRadioGroup>
```

I share this here also because I needed similiar, and there weren't many great answers around to be found.